# Application Insights - JavaScript Telemetry missing in Debug Session Telemetry

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a possibility to get the JavaScript telemetry into the debug session telemetry without connecting to Azure?

It works fine with server side code but all the telemetry for client side JavaScript is missing in debug session telemetry while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript based telemetry currently won't show in Visual Studio's debug session telemetry because that telemetry is being sent by the *browser* that's looking at the site, not the site itself, which is the thing being debugged.

at the current time there's no good/easy way for us to attach to both the browser to watch for telemetry there and to the website being debugged to watch for telemetry there.